# Immediate variable expansion in recipe

Tags: makefile

I'm making a build system and I need immediate variable expansion in a recipe of a target.

My (simplified) makefile:

```
VAR=one

all:
    @echo one is $(VAR)

VAR=two
```

When I run `make` the output is:

```
one is two
```

The output is expected (deferred expansion in recipe) but not desired.

One way to make it work is following makefile. However, this makes the recipe to be executed always, also not desired:

```
VAR=one

all: $(VAR)
    @echo one is $(VAR)

$(VAR):
    $(eval VAR=$@)

VAR=two
```

Anyone?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use something like this to get what you want. It uses [target-specific variable values](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Target_002dspecific) to capture the variable at parse-time.

```
$ cat Makefile
VAR=one

all: tgtone tgttwo

tgtone: VAR:=$(VAR)
tgtone:
        @echo $@: VAR is $(VAR)

tgttwo:
        @echo $@: VAR is $(VAR)

VAR=two
$ make
tgtone: VAR is one
tgttwo: VAR is two
```

Comment: Sometimes it's so obvious ;) Thanks Etan!

Comment: Just keep in mind that if `tgtone` has any prerequisites, the recipes of those will also inherit the target-specific variable assignment; if you want to avoid that, simply put the word `private` before the assignment.