# Reuse a Make Variable

Tags: scope, makefile

I'm compiling a lot of very similar object files using make and want to do something similar to the following:

```
BUILD_DIR := ./build/a
BUILD_DIRS += $(BUILD_DIR)

a:
    $(CC) $(BUILD_DIR)/file.c

BUILD_DIR := ./build/b
BUILD_DIRS += $(BUILD_DIR)

b:
    $(CC) $(BUILD_DIR)/file.c
```

Problem is that when I run

```
make a
```

The value of BUILD_DIR is build/b. I expected it would be build/a, when does make resolve the variable names? Is there any easy to read way to do what I want? I tried define/endef but got the same results.

Edit: Note that the suggested answer [Immediate variable expansion in recipe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29240933/immediate-variable-expansion-in-recipe) won't really solve this problem. The answer there is to use target-specific variables. Note that I also need to use the variable with a non-target-specific variable:

```
BUILD_DIRS += $(BUILD_DIR)
```

If the variable is target-specific I won't be able to use it outside of the target like I want.

Comment: "when does make resolve the variable names?" -> http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Reading-Makefiles

Comment: possible duplicate of [Immediate variable expansion in recipe](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29240933/immediate-variable-expansion-in-recipe)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Etan's answer regarding target-specific variables *will* solve your problem, you just need to realize that `:=` (immediate / simple) target-specific variables are resolved at assignment time, just like other `:=` variables.

So, this will work:

```
# Force this to be a simple variable
BUILD_DIRS :=

BUILD_DIR := ./build/a
BUILD_DIRS += $(BUILD_DIR)

a: BUILD_DIR := $(BUILD_DIR)
a:
        $(CC) $(BUILD_DIR)/file.c

BUILD_DIR := ./build/b
BUILD_DIRS += $(BUILD_DIR)

b: BUILD_DIR := $(BUILD_DIR)
b:
        $(CC) $(BUILD_DIR)/file.c
```

Personally I suspect there are better ways to do this but without more information about the requirements you really need to meet it's not useful to speculate.

Comment: Yes you are right, it will work, I don't care much for the syntax though. It's redundant and not as easy to read. I won't use variables for what I'm trying to do if this is the cleanest make can do. I posted a related follow up question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30195873/make-immediate-variable-assignment.

Comment: We can't explain "cleanest make can do" because you've not provided a complete set of requirements.  You say, for example, you have "a lot of very similar objects"... how similar are they?  If they're similar enough you can use a single pattern rule to build them all.  Do you really HAVE to keep all those lines separate?  Can you just create a single variable that lists all the target names: `ALL_BUILDS = a b` then `BUILD_DIRS = $(addprefix ./build/,$(ALL_BUILDS))` etc. etc.?

Comment: I want to 1) define several rules, 2) add each rule name to a variable, 3) I want an all rule the depends on each rule in the file, 4) I don't want to place any rule information outside of "its" section of the file, i.e. I don't want to manually add any additional information about the rule anywhere else in the file. I want to do this so its very simple and quick to add and remove new rules, which I constantly do. The follow up question I mentioned in my previous comment describes the problem in more detail.

Comment: Thanks MadScientist. My problem is solved by the answers in the other thread. Your comment there is correct too.