# Make Immediate Variable Assignment

Tags: variables, makefile

I'm having issues with immediate assignment of variables in a make file using := combined with variables assigned with +=. For example:

```
VAR := a
VARS += $(VAR)

rule1:
        echo "$(VARS)"

VAR := b
VARS += $(VAR)

rule2:
        echo "$(VARS)"
```

When I run make, regardless of the rule, it prints "b b". What I find confusing is that if I use the following make file instead:

```
VARS += a

rule1:
        echo "$(VARS)"

VARS += b

rule2:
        echo "$(VARS)"
```

It prints "a b" regardless of the rule, which is what I would expect. According to the make manual https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Reading-Makefiles.html:

> We say that expansion is immediate if it happens during the first
> phase: in this case make will expand any variables or functions in
> that section of a construct as the makefile is parsed.
>
> immediate := immediate
>
> immediate += deferred or immediate
>
> For the append operator, ‘+=’, the right-hand side is considered
> immediate if the variable was previously set as a simple variable
> (‘:=’ or ‘::=’), and deferred otherwise.

If := is actually immediate, and immediate variables are expanded as they are parsed, as the make manual says they are, then I would expect that these make files to have the same behavior. Why is that not true? I believe this is either a mistake in make's documentation or a bug in make.

Comment: Etan's answer is correct, but I think not quite on-target.  The very simple answer to your explicit question is, the reason the two makefiles have different behavior is that the `VARS` variable is _not_ an immediate variable.  The `VAR` variable is, because you set it with `:=`.  But you never set `VARS` except with `+=` and the default type of variable is always recursive (deferred).  Variable types are not inherited by assignment; setting variable X to an immediate variable Y does _not_ make X immediate too.  Etan's last paragraph in his answer, and the doc you quote above, is the key.

Comment: @MadScientist I agree with you. Setting the variable with := is the key.

Comment: @MadScientist Indeed "the" issue was the misreading of the documentation and the flavor of the `VARS` variable but the deferred nature of expansions in a recipe was a confounding factor as well. My comment on my answer attempted to clarify that as well.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The bit you are missing is that recipe lines (the bodies of rules) are not expanded at parse time (at best they could be partially expanded, think about the automatic variables like `$@` and `$^` for example) and instead are expanded at rule execution time.

This is covered in the last section of the section of the manual that you quoted above [How `make` Reads a Makefile](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Reading-Makefiles):

> **Rule Definition**
>
> A rule is always expanded the same way, regardless of the form:
>
> ```
> immediate : immediate ; deferred
>    deferred
> ```
>
> That is, the target and prerequisite sections are expanded immediately, and the recipe used to construct the target is always deferred. This general rule is true for explicit rules, pattern rules, suffix rules, static pattern rules, and simple prerequisite definitions.

So while you are correct that the assignment is immediate you missed that the expansion in the recipe context **is not**. So the recipes are **always** expanded **after** every toplevel assignment has finished.

Also, for the first example, you never set `VARS` as simply-expanded so it defaults to recursively expanded so when you write:

```
VAR := a
VARS += $(VAR)
```

and think you are doing:

```
VAR := a
VARS += a
```

you aren't.

You are actually doing what is literally written and storing `$(VAR)` in the value of `$(VARS)` so that when make finishes the value of `$(VARS)` is `$(VAR) $(VAR)` which then, naturally, expands to `b b`.

If you add `VARS :=` to the top of that first makefile example you will get `a b` as you expect (since then `VARS` is simply expanded and expands `$(VAR)` at the `+=` assignment time).

Comment: This answers the question, but the deferred attribute of the rule is not the issue, it is the := initialization of VARS. I now see that I misinterpreted this sentence: _"For the append operator, ‘+=’, the right-hand side is considered immediate if the variable was previously set as a simple variable (‘:=’ or ‘::=’), and deferred otherwise."_ I thought the variable it was referring to was the variable on the right-hand side, but that wouldn't make sense because the right-hand side of equation doesn't have to be a variable. Thanks!

Comment: There were two issues. The fact that `VARS` was not simply-expanded and the fact that rule bodies are deferred no matter what the variables they contain are. Both played a part in the confusing results you saw. But yes, misunderstanding what variable was being discussed there wouldn't help.